# admin page code igniter doesn't work because laravel valet?

Tags: php, codeigniter, laravel-valet

i have php project with ci framework. then i install laravel valet. I access my admin page using this domain myprojectname.dev/admin.  but the admin page return is 404Page Not found. can somebody help me to fix this ?

Comment: Are You using CodeIgniter + Laravel?

Comment: Laravel Valet doesn't support CodeIgniter.

Comment: just using code igniter. But I install valet so my local project can be access with domain .dev . Sorry i'm a newbie. I have local project that if i access the web page i.e myprojectname.dev it's work. but if access the admin page i.e myprojectname.dev/admin it doesn't work.  'A Database Error Occurred
Error Number: 1055'

Comment: If You using `codeigniter`s routing, then You should write like: `myprojectname.dev/index.php/admin`, if You hav not `.htaccess` file in Your root folder

Comment: did help to You? :-|

Comment: thank you for your reply, Salim :)

Comment: did it help to You +1

Comment: yes. it helps me a lot. Thank you :D

Comment: if it's help to You can You check it as right answer and upvote; I just add my answer; I will appreciate it if You do

Answer (score 0):

If You using codeigniters routing, then You should write like: `myprojectname.dev/index.php/admin`, if You hav not `.htaccess file in Your root folder